# Ember.js, How do I use Javascript in a view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm pretty new to Ember and I'm having a problem that googling and reading the docs hasn't helped me with much yet. In my index view, I have a small `<ul>` that I'm using `roundabout.js` on to make it into a carousel slider. The problem, is that for the life of me, I can't get Ember to let me use Javascript on the DOM. :( Any advice would be very appreciated.

The `<ul>` looks like:

```
<ul id="games">
                <li class="god"><img src="{{URL::asset('images/doge.png')}}" alt="doge" height="400" width="400"/></li>
                <li class="doge">Wow</li>
                <li class="doge">Much move</li>
                <li class="doge">Many Smooth</li>
                <li class="doge">Doge is world</li>
                <li class="doge">Very slide</li>
                <li class="doge">Amaze</li>
                <li class="doge">To the moon!</li>
</ul>
```

And the code to make it into a carousel is:

```
    $('#games').roundabout({
    minZ: 100,
    maxZ: 300,
    tilt: -4,
    childSelector: '.doge'
    });
```

And the finished product should look like:
[image]

Here's the ember code I used following @fanta's advice:

```
App.Index= Ember.View.extend({      
    didInsertElement : function(){
         Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function(){
            $('#games').roundabout({
            minZ: 100,
            maxZ: 300,
            tilt: -4,
            childSelector: '.doge'
            });
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: in your view, override the didInsertElement function, and put your carousel code there, that should work. App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({templateName: 'path_to_your_template', didInsertElement: function(){ //code here }})

Comment: Hrmm, didn't seem to work. I'll add that part in an edit.

Comment: wrap your code in a Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {// code})  and the code should go in the same function.

Comment: Just did that, no luck. Edited with the most current code.

Comment: do you get any javascript errors on the console ?

Comment: I really wish I was. Then I might have a clue on how to debug it.

Comment: I know it's kind of a pain but can you create a simplified fiddle of your current code?  You can use this Fiddle as your base: http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/790/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is JSFiddle with what I've told you, the only thing is that I copied and pasted the carousel code there, just go to the relevant code

http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/792/

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
        $('#games').roundabout({
            minZ: 100,
            maxZ: 300,
            tilt: -4,
            childSelector: '.doge'
        });
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: aren't you defining the App.IndexView twice ?, that has happened to me.

Comment: -_- And now I'm an idiot. That was it. I couldn't have a virtual view earlier for animated transitions, and defined it twice. Lol